# Xcode 9 - Could not attach to pid for Frameworks unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, frameworks, ios-simulator

I am getting the following error after migrating from one mac to another using time machine.

> Could not attach to pid
>
> Ensure "project title" is not already running,
> and "system username" has permission to debug it.

[image: Screenshot added.]

The error occurs only when running the unit tests for (any) Framework project. Running an application on simulator and device works fine.

Running unit tests for an application works, but running it for any framework can't be launched due to this error. I am getting this error even with Alamofire or PromiseKit unit tests.

I tested the solutions suggested on similar questions on Stackoverflow (I deleted derived data, cleaned everything, reinstalled Xcode, restarted the mac ..) nothing solved the issue till now.

I am using Xcode 9.3 and tested this with Xcode 9.4-beta also.

I am running on Mac OS High Sierra - 10.13.4 (17E199)

Any help / suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Does this happen when you check out the project from git?

Comment: @Ryan yes this happen even if I check out alamofire from GitHub for example

Comment: How do you import the 3rd party frameworks into your project? via `cocoapods`?

Comment: I am talking about running unit tests for frameworks, and I mentioned Alamofire and PromiseKit as example. These frameworks do not have dependencies, so no need to cocoapods here.  Also as I said in my question, running an application using the framework as well as running unit tests for an application that uses the framework are both working. The problem happen only when opening the framework project and trying to run its unit tests

Comment: The unit test target is different with the main target or the 3rd party library target. So you need to import them via project setting or `Podfile`(if you are using cocoapods). The question I asked was to clarify how you are importing the frameworks into your test target.

Comment: There is no third party library here. Just a framework project with it's unit tests target (generated by xcode).

Comment: So you are trying to create a framework which has `Alamofire` and `PromiseKit` as a dependency? And want to add some unit tests for the framework you created? Or you are actually forking the `Alamofire` and adding some tests?

Comment: No, my framework have no dependencies. The same issue that I have with my framework happen also with any other framework. PromiseKit and Alamofire are just examples.

Comment: I have this too. It's reproducible very easily.
New project (cocoa touch framework) - Tick the "Unit Tests" box when creating the project. Once project is created run the unit tests. Boom it fails with the error

Comment: Check if this one works https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848546/1753005

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After opening a bug report to Apple, they suggested me to:

- Check if my user is an Admin user. It was the case.
- Check if I have "_developer" group, in the output of `groups` command. it was the case. Use this command: `dscacheutil -q group`
- Check developer mode rights using the command `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -status`. The status was unknown for me.
- Enable developer mode rights if needed, using the command `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable`. This solved finally my issue!

Comment: The command for checking developer mode rights is `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -status` - notice the `/` in the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I get `Developer mode is currently enabled.` when checking the status, and `Developer mode is already enabled.` when I run those commands

Comment: @OrionEdwards have you eventually figured out the cause and solution?

Comment: @hyouuu yes, I discovered that if I rebooted my mac, the problem went away. Stupid but it worked

Comment: Thank you so much - this just fixed the issue for me with Xcode 11 Beta 4!

Comment: Two days on it and I found this. Xcode 11 Beta 4 as well. I love you. Marry me.

Answer (score 9):

If you have `Mojave` OS then:

1) Open your target scheme

[image]

2) Uncheck this one

[image]

3) Select this scheme while testing this target (ex. Testing "TestApiTarget" - select "TestApiTarget" in schemes on tests).

Its temporary solution from [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/44945549)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this issue by:

1. adding `Single View App` target (I named it `HostApp`)
2. setting `HostApp` target as a host application for test target

[image: Setting HostApp as a host application]

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am running High Sierra Beta 8, Xcode 9.4.1 & Xcode 10 Beta 6.

Comment: This worked for me too. But I'm not sure that it is clean solution. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Found another solution. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try some following steps -

1. Open the keyChain and check the `Keychain certificates` and delete the existing ones which are expired.

   2. Uncheck the - `automatically manage sign in` from Xcode project settings.
   3. Delete any derived data
   4. Clean the project by `cmd+k`
   5. Then Close and `Restart` the project and Run...

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have no expired certificates on my Keychain.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this following steps -

1. Kill your simulator and then run it again from Xcode.
2. If you are trying to build too fast after a build has started. Try 
   stopping and running the project again.
3. This can be a issue with the untrusted certificates in key-chain access, please remove such a type of certificates and re-build again.

Finally, you can do is recheck the Keychain certificates. Delete the exiting ones by right clicking (they'd passed expiration)
and unchecked `"automatically manage signing"` in `Targets->General`

Hope above steps will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the solutions you suggested but it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't seen this exact error, but I've found removing the derived data helps fix some transient errors that pop up after updates etc.

You can find the location of your derived data folder in Xcode.
Open **preferences/locations** and click the arrow.
Once in derived data you can remove all the folders. 
FYI after deleting the derived data folder all your projects will need to be rebuilt.

Hope this helps!

[image: Xcode preferences/locations]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already deleted derived data many times without any result.