# Xcode 11.3 could not attach to the pid: <Number> without internet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, macos-catalina, xcode11.3

[Error Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QqZh.png)

Xcode 11.3 not able to run the simulator when the lab being "offline" I need to connect to the internet to make the Xcode run the simulator. I found this is hard, please note I try to the following possible solutions but no one solve the problem.

- Remove driven data
- Erase all content and setting from the simulator
- Enable AuthDevTools

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651029/xcode-9-could-not-attach-to-pid

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers about this issue.

**1st way**

You should run this command in your terminal ->

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

**2nd way**

Uncheck this box ->

- Edit Scheme > Run > Debug executable

***Resource for this answer***

- [Developer Apple Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120282)

---

***Bonus***

- What is the `DevToolsSecurity -enable` command?

This is the command we can use for enable `Developer Mode`

> When you run Xcode for the first time on a fresh system, it asks if you’d like to enable Developer Mode. Developer Mode allows Xcode to execute common debugging tasks without constantly asking for your password.

[Brian Gilham's Medium Article](https://medium.com/@bgilham/how-to-enable-developer-mode-using-the-terminal-136711573da)

Comment: the problem back again after few minutes, the Xcode need to sign in with my Apple ID every time I run the project to ensure from the project team, I think. but that is bad for me.